# Wrong og:image in the Facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I did the Open Graph on my website and everything is perfect.

But, for the homepage (front_page), facebook takes an image of FOOTER (?!)

In the debug is alright. How to force facebook to make the OG: IMAGE as first image?

The code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post(); endwhile; endif;?>
<!-- the default values -->
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY ID" />

<!-- if page is home -->
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="name" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.com/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/thumbface.jpg" /> <?php } ?>

<!-- if page is content page -->
<?php if (is_single()) { ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php single_post_title(''); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_content($post->ID)); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php $fbthumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'facebook-thumb' ); echo $fbthumb[0]; ?>" />

<!-- if page is others -->
<?php } else { ?>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/thumbface.jpg" /> <?php } ?>
```

and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Debug the URL on [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). There's a possibility that your URL has been cached by Facebook even though the image would be the correct one. Using the Linter will delete the cache, and use the presently available tags on the page.

Comment: In DEBUG is all right. It shows the correct image. But when I put the LINK on facebook, it shows the og: image as the last option. The first option is a picture of the FOOTER. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Although the correct image is shown as 3rd option while choosing a thumbnail.
I think that og:image works well when the user likes the page. In case of share, the user is shown options.

I would suggest you to try 2 things:
1) Use more than 1 og:image tags and see what comes up.
2) Use the correct image after the footer and set that to hidden. Maybe FB will parse that too.